# XML Parsing - Retrieve data from multiple nested elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, nested

I've really searched in stackoverflow for a solution to my problem, but it doesn't seem like i can find it. Hopefully someone can help me!

My Problem:
I've pasted a part of the XML code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <spocosy version="1.0" responsetime="2013-05-17 04:22:07" exec="0.241">
        <query-response requestid="" service="objectquery">
            <sport name="Cycling" enetSportCode="cy" del="no" n="0" ut="2012-12-18 10:05:23" id="30">
                <tournament_template name="Tour de France 1" sportFK="30" gender="male" enetID="0" del="no" n="1" ut="2012-05-22 11:20:50" id="8844">
                    <tournament name="2011" tournament_templateFK="8844" enetSeasonID="0" del="no" locked="none" n="0" ut="2010-12-15 16:24:21" id="5830">
                        <tournament_stage name="Tour de France" tournamentFK="5830" countryFK="5" gender="male" enetID="0" startdate="2011-07-02" enddate="2011-07-24" del="no" locked="none" n="10" ut="2011-01-19 11:15:29" id="822493">
                            <event name="Stage 1" tournament_stageFK="822493" startdate="2011-07-02 13:05:00" eventstatusFK="0" status_type="finished" status_descFK="6" enetID="0" enetSportID="cy" del="no" locked="no" n="5" ut="2011-07-02 18:22:30" id="956268">
                                <properties>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="StartName" value="Rotterdam" del="yes" n="1" ut="2011-02-16 09:40:18" id="11468200"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="EndName" value="Rotterdam" del="yes" n="1" ut="2011-02-16 09:40:18" id="11468201"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="Kilometers" value="8.9" del="yes" n="1" ut="2011-02-16 09:40:18" id="11468202"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="Number" value="1" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-12-15 16:26:30" id="11468203"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="ParticipantType" value="athlete" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-12-15 16:26:30" id="11468204"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="StageType" value="flat" del="no" n="1" ut="2011-04-13 12:14:12" id="11468205"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="RaceType" value="normal" del="no" n="1" ut="2011-04-13 12:14:18" id="11468206"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="Live" value="yes" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-12-15 16:26:30" id="11468207"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="Kilometers" value="191.5" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-04-29 10:00:12" id="12250416"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="StartName" value="Passage du Gois" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-04-29 10:00:12" id="12250417"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="EndName" value="Mont des Alouettes" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-04-29 10:00:12" id="12250418"/>
                                    <property object="event" objectFK="956268" type="metadata" name="Verified" value="yes" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 18:22:30" id="12630035"/>
                                </properties>
                                <event_participant number="1" participantFK="205191" eventFK="956268" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 13:02:53" id="2811827">
                                    <participant name="Peloton" gender="male" type="athlete" countryFK="652" enetID="0" enetSportID="cy" del="no" n="1" ut="2012-05-29 23:41:56" id="205191"/>
                                </event_participant>
                                <event_participant number="2" participantFK="76544" eventFK="956268" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 13:04:33" id="2811828">
                                    <participant name="Jeremy Roy" gender="male" type="athlete" countryFK="5" enetID="866" enetSportID="cy" del="no" n="3" ut="2012-05-29 22:11:33" id="76544"/>
                                    <results>
                                        <result event_participantsFK="2811828" result_typeFK="101" result_code="duration" value="+2:33" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 18:20:36" id="10048363"/>
                                    </results>
                                </event_participant>
                                <event_participant number="3" participantFK="116303" eventFK="956268" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 13:05:01" id="2811829">
                                    <participant name="Perrig Quemeneur" gender="male" type="athlete" countryFK="5" enetID="2040" enetSportID="cy" del="no" n="1" ut="2012-05-29 23:41:56" id="116303"/>
                                    <results>
                                        <result event_participantsFK="2811829" result_typeFK="101" result_code="duration" value="+4:30" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 18:20:40" id="10048477"/>
                                        <result event_participantsFK="2811829" result_typeFK="100" result_code="rank" value="178" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 18:20:40" id="10048478"/>
                                    </results>
                                </event_participant>
                                <event_participant number="4" participantFK="167312" eventFK="956268" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 13:05:14" id="2811830">
                                    <participant name="Lieuwe Westra" gender="male" type="athlete" countryFK="9" enetID="2379" enetSportID="cy" del="no" n="1" ut="2012-05-29 23:48:32" id="167312"/>
                                    <results>
                                        <result event_participantsFK="2811830" result_typeFK="101" result_code="duration" value="+2:25" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 17:53:10" id="10048214"/>
                                        <result event_participantsFK="2811830" result_typeFK="100" result_code="rank" value="111" del="no" n="0" ut="2011-07-02 17:53:10" id="10048215"/>
                                    </results>
                                </event_participant>
```

I want to fetch attributes from the different elements including the nested ones. I want to create an object with the values.

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Mini_Project_Tour_De_France.TourDeFranceModel
{
    public class XmlParser
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; } = "Cycling.xml";
        public List<Cyclist> participants { get; set; } = new List<Cyclist>();
        public string typeOfSport { get; set; }
        public XDocument doc { get; set; }
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }


        public XmlParser()
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            getParticipants();
            getEventStartDate_EndDate();
            getTypeOfSport();
        }
```

The method PARSING XML:

```
 public void getParticipants()
        {
            if (fileName != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<Cyclist> decendants = from c in doc.Descendants("event_participant") 
                                 select new Cyclist()

                                 {
                                     Name = c.Element("participant").Attribute("name").Value,
                                     gender = c.Element("participant").Attribute("gender").Value,
                                     type = c.Element("participant").Attribute("type").Value,
                                     countryFK = int.Parse(c.Element("participant").Attribute("countryFK").Value),
                                     enetID = int.Parse(c.Element("participant").Attribute("enetID").Value),
                                     enetSportID = (c.Element("participant").Attribute("enetSportID").Value),
                                     del = c.Element("participant").Attribute("del").Value,
                                     n = int.Parse(c.Element("participant").Attribute("n").Value),
                                     id = int.Parse(c.Element("participant").Attribute("id").Value),
                                     // This ut is a dateType. It's an attribute inside the element <result> which is inside <results> which is inside <event_participant>. 
                                     //How can i get it?
                                     ut = Convert.ToDateTime(c.Element("results").Element("result").Attribute("ut").Value),
                                     // Same problem here.
                                     rank = c.Element("results").Element("result").Attribute("result_code").Value
                                 };

                participants = decendants.ToList();


            }

        }
```

Here i'm trying to create a cyclist object with all the data it needs. I am having a hard time trying to explain what i want to happen. Maybe one of you can see what i'm trying to do? If not, tell me and i will try and explain it better.

Cylist class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Mini_Project_Tour_De_France.TourDeFranceModel
{
    public class Cyclist
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int countryFK { get; set; }
        public string enetSportID { get; set; }
        public int enetID { get; set; }
        public int n { get; set; }
        public string del { get; set; }
        public DateTime ut { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string resultTime { get; set; }
        public string rank { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("Name: {0} gender: {1} type: {2}+ countryFK: {3} enetSportID: {4} enetID: {5} n: {6} del: {7} ut:{8} id:{9} resultTime:{10} rank: {11}"
                ,Name,gender,type,countryFK,enetSportID,enetID,n,del,ut,id,resultTime,rank)
            ;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's only the last 2 properties of Cyclist object that i can't get to work. It's when i want to get the value of an attribute that is not inside the element "participant". :)

Comment: 1) provide a well-structured XML example 2) provide a well-structured `XmlParser` class (at least include closing bracket) 3) provide the `Cyclist` class 4) define `can't get to work`. In essence, make it easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new XmlParser(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Cyclist
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public  int countryFK { get; set; }
        public int enetID { get; set; }
        public string enetSportID { get; set; }
        public string del { get; set; }
        public int n { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime ut { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }
    public class Result
    {
        public int event_participantsFK { get; set; }
        public int result_typeFK { get; set; }
        public string result_code { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string del { get; set; }
        public int n { get; set; }
        public DateTime ut { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
    public class XmlParser
    {
        public List<Cyclist> participants { get; set; }
        public string typeOfSport { get; set; }
        public XDocument doc { get; set; }
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }


        public XmlParser(string fileName)
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            getParticipants();
            //getEventStartDate_EndDate();
            //getTypeOfSport();
        }
        public void getParticipants()
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                participants = doc.Descendants("event_participant").Select(c => new Cyclist() {
                    Name = (string)c.Element("participant").Attribute("name"),
                    gender = (string)c.Element("participant").Attribute("gender"),
                    type = (string)c.Element("participant").Attribute("type"),
                    countryFK = (int)c.Element("participant").Attribute("countryFK"),
                    enetID = (int)c.Element("participant").Attribute("enetID"),
                    enetSportID = (string)c.Element("participant").Attribute("enetSportID"),


                    del = (string)c.Element("participant").Attribute("del"),
                    n = (int)c.Element("participant").Attribute("n"),
                    id = (int)c.Element("participant").Attribute("id"),
                    ut = (DateTime)c.Element("participant").Attribute("ut"),
                    results = c.Descendants("result").Select(y => new Result() {
                        event_participantsFK = (int)y.Attribute("event_participantsFK"),
                        result_typeFK = (int)y.Attribute("result_typeFK"),
                        result_code = (string)y.Attribute("result_code"),
                        value = (string)y.Attribute("value"),
                        del = (string)y.Attribute("del"),
                        n = (int)y.Attribute("n"),
                        ut = (DateTime)y.Attribute("ut"),
                        id = (int)y.Attribute("id")
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            }

        }
    }

}
```